# How to manage GPUImage movieFile Processing in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gpuimage

I have implemented `GPUImage` library to apply filters in existing videos, Now issue is that the application is crash when I lock device, I Have also set `BOOL` variable to get application current state, Bun unfortunately resignActive call after application crash. The crash happen in this line of code.

```
[self.context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

Can you please suggest me what is best way to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(EnterBackground:)
                                                name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                              object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(DidBecomeActive:)
                                                name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                              object:nil];

}
- (void)EnterBackground:(NSNotification*)notification{
    NSLog(@"Enter in background");
        [self.movieFile endProcessing];
        [self.filter removeAllTargets];
        [self.movieFile removeAllTargets];
}

- (void)DidBecomeActive:(NSNotification*)notification{
    [_movieFile startProcessing];
}
```

Don't forget to remove observer in `viewWillDisappear`